# how to get a user contacts in telegram bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram

hi i am making a telegram bot that takes a channel id (which the use is admin in) and then adds the telegram contacts of the user in that channel. problem is that, i havent found any method in python telegram library to get the user contacts.

i tried using the phonenumbers library but that didnt work because its not something general and depends a lot on user permissions and device. i wanted to use telethon methods to get the contacts but it says i have to make  a telegram application with api hash and id.

my idea is that i should make a script with telethon module and get the user contacts and then import the script to my bot code and use the contacts information there.

is it a good idea or do you have any better solutions?